# Call by reference and ostream and string manipulation recursive

Tags: c++, recursion, reference, overflow, call

all! 
I am trying to get my program to work correctly, and I do not think it is supposed to be recursive The program is supposed to print certain strings in a text file and put them in a text-made box. 
However, I modified it incorrectly and made an infinite loop (it actually is a stack overflow, ha ha, how funny...). Any help would be much appreciated. 
here is the code for the prototype (and yes #include is used):

```
void textBox(ostream & out, string text);
```

and the part in the main function and subprogram:

```
cout << "Part c: textBox(text)" << endl ;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl ;
    ofstream fout("myFile.txt");
    string box = "Text in a Box!";
    textBox(fout, box);

    fout << endl;
string size = "You can put any text in any size box you want!!";
textBox(fout,size);

fout << endl;
string courage = "What makes the muskrat guard his musk? Courage!";
textBox(fout,courage);

void textBox(ostream & out, string text)
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  This routine outputs text surrounded by a box.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    ofstream myFile("myFile.txt");
    textBox(cout, "Message to screen");
    textBox(myFile, "Message to file");
    int textSize = text.size();

    out << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(textSize+1) << right << '+' << endl;
    out << '|' << text << '|' << endl;
    out << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(textSize+1) << right << '+' << endl;

    out << setfill(' ') ;       
}
```

Comment: Formatting helps make your code readable.

Comment: Every time you call the function `textBox`, you call it again, and again, and again...

Comment: It's recursive because `textBox` calls itself. What exactly is the intended output to myFile.txt? Do you mean to call a different function in `textBox`?  Maybe you shouldn't call functions there at all.

Comment: The strings "String in a Box", etc are supposed to be outputted to a text file by the textBox.

Comment: Too basic: "why do my recursive calls result in recursive calls?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recursive because `textBox` calls itself.  Your program will run if you:

A) Remove both calls to `textBox` within `textBox`

or B) make `textBox` like this:

```
void textBox(ostream & out, string text)
{
    int const textSize = text.size() + 1;

    out << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(textSize) << right << '+' << endl;
    out << '|' << text << '|' << endl;
    out << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(textSize) << right << '+' << endl;

    out << setfill(' ') ;
}
```

And create another function:

```
void textBoxWithInfo(ostream & out, string text)
{
    textBox(cout, "Message to screen");

    { // Braces to deallocate + close myFile faster
        ofstream myFile("myFile.txt");
        textBox(myFile, "Message to file");
    }

    textBox(out, text);
}
```

And call the above function in `main`.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: @TriHard8 I've revised it.

Comment: hopefully OP accepts your answer.  I don't even think they have a clue what they're doing.

Comment: @TriHard8 Yeah, it seems like it should be obvious that a function can't call itself on every return path.